# cakephp get realpath of view and layout

Tags: cakephp, layout, realpath

How can i retrieve absolute path of view and layout file in cakephp action.
I cant find useful method or property in

```
// in action
var_dump($this);
```

Thank

desire out put is

```
/home/sweb/www/cakeapp/app/View/Layout/mylayout.ctp
/home/sweb/www/cakeapp/app/View/Mycntl/myaction.ctp
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use this to create a full path.

```
APP . 'View' . DS . 'Layout' . DS . $this->layout
```

Which will output something like this for you,

`string '/Users/david/Sites/ExampleSite/app/View/Layout/default' (length=56)`

In order to get the view, I'd use

```
APP . 'View' . DS . $this->modelClass . DS . $this->view
```

Comment: and what about plugins actions ?

Comment: As a plugin is a Cake app just in a folder this will all still work from within a plugins controller methods.

Comment: For a path within a plugin use CakePlugin::path($this->plugin) instead of APP